# Appending Div to a nested element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to append a div to .ui-block-a and .ui-block-b

```
<div id="productionCosts" class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">
   <div id="5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8">
      <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:30%"></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:70%"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried

```
  $("#5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8").closest('.ui-grid-a').find('.ui-block-a:first').append('<div></div');
```

And

```
 $("#5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8").closest('.ui-grid-a').find('.ui-block-b:first').append('<div></div');
```

But this does not work any suggestions?

Comment: when you face problems like this in the future it's good to debug your selector train. stuff like console.log($("#5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8").closest('.ui-grid-a')) if it comes up empty then you know you're on the wrong path from the start.

Comment: Is the HTML loaded before this runs? What does  $("#5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8").closest('.ui-grid-a').find('.ui-block-a:first') return? Break it down a little at a time to determine what's happening.

Comment: As some of the answers stated, .closest() is for going up the dom, not down, so this won't return the proper element. Also always a good idea to check the jquery api, because it states this there.

Answer (score 2):

`.ui-grid-a` is a descendant of `#5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8`, so using `closest()` won't work as it looks for parents, you need `find()`

```
$("#5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8").find('.ui-grid-a .ui-block-b:first').append('<div></div');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('#5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8').find('.ui-block-a').append('hi');
```

just use `.find();` will get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#5a7d47e2-a0b3-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8 > .ui-grid-a > div").append('<div></div>');
```